# Which tool should I trust, mii-tool and ethtool don't show me the same values

Tags: linux, ethernet, gigabit-ethernet, ethtool

Our hosting company provides all the switching infrastructure for our servers. The private network, connected to `eth2` *should* be GbE. Recently I've been suspecting that something is misconfigured as cacti graphs never appear to show more than 100mbit of traffic on the link.

Digging further I found that `mii-tool` and `ethtool` do not agree on the link speed.

```
# mii-tool eth2
eth2: negotiated 100baseTx-FD flow-control, link ok
# ethtool eth2 
Settings for eth2:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
```

Which tool should I trust ?

Comment: Since this is a bit Linux specific, I added a Linux tag

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since mii-tool is deprecated, I'd go for ethtool. Can't you check the other sides opinion of the link speed, btw?

mii-tool and ethtool are known to disagree in certain circumstances; you can find bugreports of that on a host of websites. What driver are you using? At least tg3 is known to be a subject of [disagreement](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=199462) between the two tools.

**UPDATE:** Checked it for you locally, but it seems mii-tool can only report upto 100MiB/s. ethtool is therefore probably right in your situation ;-) Must be the reason it is deprecated, anyway...

Comment: The interface is a Broadcom. 04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5751 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (rev 21)

Comment: mii-tool is really unhappy on 10GE interfaces. :)

Comment: ethtool and lshw both appear to be correct/reliable in my case (when mii-tool is being unreliable)

Answer (score 7):

Check `dmesg`. Most drivers will report the speed and duplex they negotiate at. For example:

> `dmesg | grep eth2`

For example, our HP Proliants have onboard Broadcom NICs that produce kernel log messages like this:

> `bnx2: eth2 NIC Link is Up, 1000 Mbps full duplex, receive & transmit flow control ON`

If your computer has been up for awhile and the kernel log buffer filled up with other stuff (it's a fixed-size FIFO), you can also check syslog. You don't say what distribution you're using, but many will log kernel messages to `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/syslog`.

Answer (score 0):

The utility ethtool has lied to me in the past, especially on interfaces that are not fully configured or in use.

Thoughput tests don't lie. If you can exceed 100M/b throughput, you know you must be running GigE.